# Get nearest location in map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, ios6

I'm doing an app which includes map functionality. I have search functionality in map. But I need to search in such a way that when I search a location with name the place which is nearest to me with that name should be shown in the map. For example I’m standing in 
Australia and if there is a place new jersey(for example) in Australia then it should show the location new jersey in Australia and not in America. Can we do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you want..you want to find wot the city name of your current location?

Comment: No he wants to restrict the result to his "area" (which will be a topic in itself: "what is my current area"! Earth? continent?...). If there is a result in the city of his current location it's of course OK, but he wrote "in Australia" and not in US...

Answer (score 0):

you can get data with your near location from googleAPI here is the example just try and see the data and also create your googleAPIKey from googleAPI site and pass your location lat long and get data mate..

also you can set differenet type like food,restaurant,atm,etc..

the google API Developer throught you can create googleAPIKey and laso see this tutorial from this link [Google API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)..

try this bellow example

```
   NSURL *strurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB7YTFTYyk9eb8ULNGxoy06-b_0DUOqdrY"];
    NSLog(@"\n\n URL %@",str);
   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:strurl];

   [request setDelegate:self];

   [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: @Kiron see this link also with brief description https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: But Paras this gives a whole lot of places. I just need to show the one place which is nearest to me

Comment: @Kiron you can add area with "radius" parameter see the url with parameter and also type name and just refer this great tutorial i give u link just see and follow this.. you'll get many idea and many new things from this.. :)

Comment: no the radius parameter wont help me bro because if its not present in a radius it has to show another which is the closest and which is inside another radius without any invocation

Comment: @Kiron first refer tutorial after that see every paramaeter description and then if you not get it then tell me dude and its not a mater that radious you can get data with your inputed location lat-long with your area just it..

Comment: I refered the tutorial bro but it will return only list of places and i just need only one place and also that should be the nearest

Comment: that was an option but the first record may not be the one with the nearest. It usually shows the most popular mate :(

Comment: i try to arrange it with nearest 1 place i'll post code if i got it mate.. :)